# For someone who already has enough cash to buy a home, isn't it better to wait and take mortgage when interest rates are high?

Tags: income-tax, mortgage, interest-rate, arbitrage, municipal-bonds

Contrary to [common wisdom in media](http://money.cnn.com/2016/12/15/real_estate/rising-mortgage-rates/index.html) the reasons why I think that taking mortgage at higher interest rates may make more sense are that:

1. Almost all mortgages are **callable by borrower**. Hence, if you took mortgage at high interest rates, then borrower would always have this extra right to renegotiate better interest rates just in case interest rates went down. Borrower is less likely to be able to leverage this opportunity when mortgage was taken at historically low interest rates.
2. Based on historical data the **Municipal Bond Arbitrage** (by "shorting" your mortgage and "longing" Muni bonds) looks like a better opportunity in high interest rate environment because proportional spread between both yields is lower and more of tax savings can be leveraged. Though, as it was pointed in one of the answers most of Muni bonds are callable as well, but to my knowledge the rules are not that good as on mortgages (e.g. muni bond refinancing can happen on previously specified dates only).

As an example, let's go back to 1990. The [mortgage rates](http://mortgage-x.com/images/graph/fhfb_contract_rate.gif) were close to 10% and [Muni Bonds](https://2zeobl3ojpj43evvq11p5yodq7e-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/Historical-Municipal-Bond-Yields.png) were yielding 7.5%. Let's assume you already had $100,000 in savings account and a home costs $100,000.

If you wanted, you could have paid for home with cash. However, you could also take mortgage and invest your cash in Muni Bonds.

Now, if you invest that money in Muni bonds yielding 7.5% and take mortgage for $100,000 at 10%, then, assuming 30% federal and 10% state tax:

1. incoming interest payments from Muni bonds pre-tax would be $7,500. Since Muni bonds are tax exempt at federal and state level, then post-tax income would still remain at $7,500.
2. outgoing interest payments from mortgage pre-tax would be $10,000. Since mortgage payments are tax deductible at federal and state level, then post-tax it would be ~ $6,000 (assuming 30% federal and 10% state tax).

This means $1,500 Muni Bond arbitrage opportunity back in 1990 which was high interest rate environment.

Now following scenarios can unfold after 1990:

1. if interest rates go lower, then you can refinance your mortgage and cut outgoing interest payments. Incoming interest payments from Muni bonds would stay the same (assuming they are not callable by borrower).
2. if interest rates stay the same then you can keep taking advantage of $1,500 arbitrage.
3. if interest rates keep going up, then you can still keep taking advantage of $1,500 arbitrage.

**What am I missing here? Some things that crossed my mind:**

1. Am I misestimating Muni Bond default risks? Or overestimating post-tax yield back in 1990 due to potentially different tax code back then?
2. I made assumption that buyer already has enough cash to buy a home. If buyer does not have this cash then he can't do the Muni Bond Arbitrage anymore. Though I think this would somewhat hint that people in low interest environment are taking mortgage not because "it makes financial sense", but because "they act in irrational fear of missing out".
3. Have the times changed and such Muni Bond arbitrage would not be possible anymore in 2018 because if mortgage rates would go back to 10%, then Muni Bonds this time would stay only at 6% (e.g. because markets have become more efficient and reduced arbitrage opportunities). How about other bonds in this case?
4. Anything else that I may be missing?

**Update#1 (To explain benefits of mortgage refinancing):**

The arbitrage trade I described above could be viewed as a three leg trade, where

1. First leg is physical home (you are long this leg in hopes to resell your home for more than when you bought);
2. Second leg is Muni Bonds (you are long this leg too, because it is nice to have bond that yields more than current interest rates);
3. Third leg is mortgage debt (you are short this leg. Once you get rid of this leg you don't have debt obligations anymore).

The market value of Second and Third leg moves together with interest rates and cancel out each other (because one is short, the other is long). By granting borrower rights to refinance he can basically eliminate any losses on the Third shorted leg at lenders expense who has to accept that this borrower won't pay anymore high interest rates on his mortgage.

Comment: So you're better off getting a high interest mortgage because maybe in the future you can refinance for a lower rate?  Why not just start with the low rate?  The arb opportunity is an interesting thought but most people with mortgages are borrowing the money because they HAVE to.

Comment: (1) When it's time to buy a house, you buy it.  You don't wait years to purchase based on the hope of a higher rates so that you can take advantage of an arbitrage.  You presented an interesting premise but when it comes to something like buying a house, I would adhere to the theory of SH*T HAPPENS so avoid trying to squeeze out a few bucks while risking home security.

Comment: (2) Default is a risk, perhaps very small but who would have ever dreamed that Blue Chip bastions like Lehman Brothers and Bear Stearns would vaporize?  Or that Enron would buy stable utility Portland General and all pensions would vaporize as well. And then there's always the chance that tax law is changed (deductions?).  Buy the house and be debt and risk free.

Comment: @quid 1) The arbitrage trade I described could be viewed as a three leg trade, where First leg is physical home (you are long this leg); Second leg is Muni Bonds (you are long this leg too); Third leg is mortgage debt (you are short this leg). The market value of Second and Third leg moves together with interest rates and cancel out each other. Unless borrower refinances and effectively eliminate losses on the 3) shorted leg. This refinancing is only possible if interest rates were initially high.

Comment: @quid 2) Based on historical data it seems that Muni yield to Mortgage interest rate ratio looks better in High interest environment. For example In 1990 it was 3:4. In 2010 it was 2:3. The higher this ratio gets the more home buyer gets in mortgage interest deductions and muni bond interest exemptions.

Comment: I think the obvious thing you're missing is the value of living in the home you've purchased.  Especially if you live in an area where 1) Average home prices have roughly tripled in ~15 years; and 2) So have apartment rentals, so that a halfway decent apartment now rents for quite a bit more than your mortgage payment.

Comment: @jamesqf Everyone who bought home 15 years ago bought it in high interest rate environment, which supports my thesis that it was good time to buy. Nevertheless there are two variables in play - interest rate and home value (See update#1 where I described the three legged trade). For this discussion I wanted to focus only on interest rate variable and not home value. However, if these two variables are related then most likely the relationship is that home values are lower in high interest rate environment, which further supports my thesis that buying home in high interest environment is better

Comment: @Hans Solo: 15 years ago was only a high-rate environment if you use today's historically low rates as a basis for comparison.  Around 6-7%, vs the 17% or so of the early '80s: http://www.freddiemac.com/pmms/pmms30.html

Comment: Your thesis as stated in the question is not "It was good to take a mortgage in the 90s" (which would be true), it is "It is better to wait until mortgage rates rise"  Your evidence that A > 0 does not prove A > B when also B > 0.

Comment: @HansSolo: Found the other mistake in your numbers: You are treating the entire municipal bond yield as tax exempt, but only interest is exempt, capital gains are not.

Answer (score 4):

No.

The hole in the plan is that not only is there some small risk in bonds (Orange County 1994?), but also bond issuers can and do refinance just like mortgage holders can when interest rates drop.

Original answer:

Whether or not there may be some investment opportunity that is sufficiently low risk and high yield to be worth mortgaging your primary residence does not depend on absolute interest rates, but on the difference between the yield and the mortgage rate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, based on historical data it seems that Muni yield to Mortgage interest rate ratio consistently looks better in High interest rate environments. For example In 1990 it was 3:4. In 2010 it was 2:3. The closer this ratio gets to 1:1 the more home buyer can receives in mortgage interest tax deductions and muni bond tax exemptions. In other words Muni Bond arbitrage looks more attractive in high interest environment. Also, feel free to chime in on the first point where borrower looses the rights to refinance if mortgage was taken at historically low interest rates.

Comment: "borrower looses the rights to refinance" Borrower has *no need* to refinance. Refinancing is a nice option to have if rates are lower than when you took out the mortgage. You don't need it if they're not.

Answer (score 3):

> Anything else that I may be missing?

I can't speak to municipal bond arbitrage, but this piece caught my eye:

> outgoing interest payments from mortgage pre-tax would be $10,000.
>   Since mortgage is tax deductible at federal and state level, then
>   post-tax it would be ~ $6,000 outgoing payment.

Many people do not get full benefit from mortgage interest deduction. For example, I found a return I prepared where about $10k in mortgage interest was paid, the total itemized deductions were only $15k, the standard deduction that year was $12.6k (married), so the $10k in mortgage interest only benefited them $600 (federal, so a little more with state).

This is pretty typical from what I've seen, and under the new law even fewer people will benefit from itemizing, making the interest deduction less valuable than ever. There are also limits to how much mortgage interest you can deduct (only interest from first $750k of mortgage debt as of 2018) and an itemized deduction phase out for high-income households. Might be a sweet spot in the middle, but can't just assume full deduction benefit just because it's deductible.

Comment: Good point. However, in high interest rate environment it is easier to go over the standard deduction cap. Imagine 750K loan and 10% interest rate on mortgage. That would total 75K in interest payments. Whereas today at 4% that would be ~30K and subsidy to buy home with mortgage looks less tempting because there is not much difference from standard deduction. I think this a actually supports my thesis that taking mortgage in high interest rate environment is better. Of course mortgage over 750K is different story as you pointed out.

Comment: Easier to get into the itemizing range, but unless you had other deductions that would get you even with the standard deduction, a portion of the mortgage interest would have no benefit. If married filing jointly next year, that's a chunk at 24k standard deduction.

Comment: @HansSolo: "But I can deduct it on my taxes" is **never** a justification for throwing away money.  Tax deductions reduce the net cost of e.g. charitable contributions, but they are still a net cost.

Comment: @BenVoigt For majority of cases contributing to 401(k) is a good idea, because you can "deduct it from taxes", right? Now irrelevant from whether you have mortgage on house or bought house with cash you will still have property taxes that can be deducted. If **property tax amount already approaches standard deduction amount** then everything else being the same I don't see how optimizing for mortgage interest deductions is different than optimizing for 401(k) deductions. Again 401(k) probably is good idea across majority of population while interest deduction is for lesser population.

Comment: @HansSolo You risk is a change to the tax code that negates the benefit you've hinged your investment strategy on, but you're right.

Comment: @HansSolo: There is all the difference in the world.  Contributions made to a Traditional 401(k) are **still my money**.  I get a tax benefit in exchange for restrictions on when I can spend that money, my money.  Mortgage interest is totally different.  You're giving it to the bank and **you will never see it again**.  If you intentionally wait for a higher interest rate, you get a bigger tax benefit in exchange for **giving money away to the bank**, money that otherwise would still be yours.  That's not a bargain at all, since the tax benefit is never as large as the expense.

Comment: @BenVoigt The money after claiming mortgage deductions would still be your money that you did not pay to IRS. Also, view these mortgage deductions **only and only** in context of doing beforementioned arbitrage with Tax-exempt Bonds (opposed to keeping cash in safebox). However, as Hart pointed out with this strategy you have to hope that mortgage deduction and standard deduction laws won't change against you. Or, that, if mortgage deduction laws do change you are hoping that you will get grandfathered (i.e. like with 2018 changes where principal got capped to 750K only for all new mortgages).

Comment: @HansSolo: No, it's not still your money.  The mortgage interest is the bank's.  Your numbers in the question appear to assume that you get your entire effective income tax rate back on mortgage interest.  But you don't, social security and FICA don't come back to you.  Next, if you invest the value of the house when bonds are paying 7.5%, you are still better off if you took the mortgage when rates were 4% instead of waiting until rates are 10%.  Finally, no bank will loan to you at 10% when bonds are 7.5%, because their after-tax profit on 10% is less.

Comment: If the bank has the opportunity to take money and invest in tax-free bonds at 7.5%, they will do so, unless your mortgage makes them more money after taxes are considered.  With the new 2018 tax rules, corporate tax rates are only 25%, so that 10% mortgage makes them 7.5% after taxes but before their expenses and risk.  In the 90s, the corporate income tax rate was 34-35%, so they're only making 6.5% before expenses.  They'll never loan under terms that are less profitable than putting the same money into bonds.